# Null value in column "user_id" of relation "authentication_junioruser" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to do **POST** request and getting error:
***IntegrityError at /accounts/juniorprofile/**
null value in column "user_id" of relation "authentication_junioruser" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, Ms K, Vadim, t, 99999999, , null, , 2022-10-23, , DevOps, , , set(), , null, null).*

Junior User is inherited from the custom User model

```
class ListCreateUserProfile(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = JuniorUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JuniorProfileSerializer
```

**views.py**

```
class JuniorProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    language = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE)
    work_experience = ExperienceSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    education = EducationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    course = CourseSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = JuniorUser
        fields = ['id', 'terms_is_accepted', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'phone_number', 'telegram_nick', 'linkedin', 'location',
                  'profile_photo', 'date_of_birth', 'specialization', 'hard_skills',
                  'soft_skills', 'language', 'work_experience', 'education',
                  'course', 'other_info', 'portfolio_link']
```

**serializers.py**

```
class JuniorUser(models.Model):
    """
    This model points to an instance of User model and expands that one to determine the role of Junior User.
    All the class attributes was got from the technical requirements 'Registration form'
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="junior")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) if self.user else ''
```

**models.py**

Comment: `not-null constraint` simply means the table in which you're trying to create or update data that table has some field that cannot stay `Null` so you have to give that field a Value.

Comment: you need to create User instance before JouniorUser.